# Accessing the element type in XML using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

As seen in the code snippet below, the name given to each of my elements in the XML file vary. Element 1 is of type `testcheck1` and Element 2 is of type `testcheck2.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

<Tests xmlns="urn:lst-emp:emp">

  <testcheck1 xmlns="">
    <Type>string</Type>
    <Value>value1</Value>
  </testcheck1>

  <testcheck2 xmlns="">
    <Type>int</Type>
    <Value>1232</Value>
  </testcheck2>

</Tests>
```

I can use this code:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("project_data.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
Console.WriteLine("List of all Values:");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("C:\\tempFolder\\results.xml", true);
    file2.WriteLine(employee.Element("Value").Value);
    file2.Close();
}
```

to get each of the values in the XML file. (like `value1` and `1232`).

I was wondering if it were possible to get the element types that I have defined in the XML (like `testcheck1` and `testcheck2`) using LINQ to XML.

Comment: Sure - just use `employee.Name` to get the `XName`, or `employee.Name.LocalName` to get the local part of it. It's not clear why you want to open the file separately for every employee, mind you... (Note that that's if you want `testcheck1` or `testcheck2` as the values... if you want `int` or `string`, that's asking for the `Type` element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're really just looking for the element name, possibly its [`LocalName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var root = XElement.Load("project_data.xml");
foreach (var element in root.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", 
                      element.Name.LocalName,
                      element.Element("Value").Value);
}
```

(Talking about the "type" of an element when you *also* have a `Type` child element is a bit confusing, mind you...)

That will print out:

```
testcheck1: value1
testcheck2: 1232
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted. Also, sorry about the minor confusion there. I should have seen it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `Type` element same way as `Value` element:

```
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("C:\\tempFolder\\results.xml", true);
    var value = (string)employee.Element("Value");
    var type = (string)employee.Element("Type");
    var name = e.Name.LocalName;
    // ...
}
```

You also can create list of anonymous 'employee' objects with value and type:

```
var employees = from e in xelement.Elements()
                select new {
                   Name = e.Name.LocalName,
                   Type = (string)e.Element("Type"),
                   Value = (string)e.Element("Value")
                };

foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    // use employee.Name, employee.Type and employee.Value
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I got you confused by having an attribute also called 'Type'. What I meant was the element name. +1 for the effort regardless and this sparks some thinking about my solution.

Comment: @John no problem, updated with local name retrieving